# Refactoring parameter list of perl subroutines

Tags: perl, refactoring

I'm currently refactoring some application code and I want to be able to remove some parameters from a subroutine. For example, let's say I have the following[1]:

```
sub do_something {
    my ( $param1, $param2, $param3, $param4 ) = ( @_ );
    ....
}
```

However, as part of the refactoring I've made parameters 2 and 3 redundant. Updating this method signature is the easy part, but is there a straightforward way of updating all the calls to it?

I've been doing down the road of some bespoke grep/sed/perl to do it, but some of the calls to the sub are over multiple lines which makes it a pain, and every time I do this on a project it's bespoke. Are there tools that are good for doing this particular refactoring?

[1] - Not actual parameter or subroutine names, I assure you!

Comment: I'm not aware of any shortcuts, but is your problem finding the calls into the method reliably, or editing them to comply with the new interface?

Comment: Finding them is easy enough. All instances are in one package and can be found using grep. It's editing that's the issue. I could do some scripting to explode the calling param list and put it back together again, but this is likely to be bespoke. Maybe it's time to write myself my own refactoring module.

Comment: You state that the calls are sometimes spread over multiple lines, so I assume that there is non-trivial computation going on for generating those parameters.  So I'd expect manual clean up on many call sites to be necessary, since merely removing the parameters might only remove some of mentioned computations.  For example there might be lines just before the call that will become redundant as well.

Comment: There will definitely be redundant lines leading up to the calls. My plan is to remove the parameters and then use the wonders of git diff to check which variables are now redundant and remove those as well.

Answer (score 3):

[Padre](http://padre.perlide.org) has some functionality for refactoring, but I don't know whether it can accomplish what you want.

Change your interface to accept hashes instead of positional lists, this will make future changes less work than now.

```
sub do_something {
    my (%param) = (@_);
    ...
}

do_something(foo => 23, bar => 42);
```

Comment: Using a hash for the parameters seems somehow wrong (not sure why, probably just because I don't currently do it!), but I think it might be the way to go once a subroutine has more than a couple of parameters. I'll give Padre a good as well.

Comment: You shouldn't feel that way. It's a [best practice, see chapter 9.4](http://oreilly.com/catalog/perlbp).

Comment: Aha! Another book to add to my list to purchase. Thanks!

Comment: I would add that using hashes in this way does not absolve you from handling the parameters in detail, including cleaning up non-necessary inputs to methods. From experience I can tell you that Perl code stacks that pass hash references (called e.g. `%param` everywhere) up and down abstraction layers with little or no validation can cost significant time to maintain and debug. If you name the keys well, though, daxim's answer here will help you find where redundant params are being passed in.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a test suite that has near 100% code coverage, you can use this to find all call sites.

Given an argument for the position in the callstack, the `caller` builtin returns

1. The caller's package name
2. Filename
3. Line number
4. Fully qualified sub name
5. … and some more

We can now add a bit of code that logs the position of calls. We can either put the result into some data structure for automatic processing, or write a report to a log file. E.g.

```
sub this_logs {
  {
    # seperate scope to not pollute your sub
    state $log_fh //= do {
      open my $fh, ">", "record_callsites.log"; # assuming autodie;
      $fh;
    };
    state $seen = {};
    my (undef,    undef, undef, $sub) = caller(1);
    my ($package, $file, $line,     ) = caller(0);
    my $site = $sub ? "$sub()" : "pkg $package";
    unless ($seen->{$file}{$line}++) {
      say {$log_fh} "CALL from $site at $file line $line";
    }
  }
  my ($param1, $param2) = @_;
  # etc
}
```

Assuming all your code was

```
this_logs(1, 2, 3);         # direct call
foo();                      # call from same package
my $sub = "this_" . "logs"; 
baz($sub);                  # call by name
Foo::bar();                 # call from different package
foo();                      # duplicate call

sub foo {
  return this_logs(5, 6, 7);
}
sub baz {
  shift()->(1, 2, 3);  # no strict refs for this, please
};

package Foo;
sub bar {
  main::this_logs();
}
```

This would produce the log file

```
CALL from pkg main at - line 20
CALL from main::foo() at - line 28
CALL from main::baz() at - line 31
CALL from Foo::bar() at - line 3
```

(File name `-` means STDIN)

So given a suitable test suite, this is able to find call sites that can't be grepped for.

If you have a non-moronic editor, you could also emit a script that opens each file in turn and positions the cursor on the correct line:

```
say "kate -l $line $file";
say "vim +$line $file";
```

Comment: Funnily enough, this is a function internal to a test suite, so I'd darn well hope it has 100% coverage! This looks amazingly useful. I'll give it a test run as soon as I can.